# Open External Link with Crosswalk Webview got Application Error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, crosswalk

I want to make webview to show my webpage with crosswalk plugin. When I put my url, and click the button. I got error 
"Application Error"
"net:ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
(https://example.dummy.com:8444)"

my home page is using https

this is my code :

home.html

```
<ion-slide>
    <h2>Please, Enjoy to call with our customer service</h2>
    <button ion-button block full (click)="goToPage('https://oscar2.kebhana.co.id:8444/gibPT/intn/info/call#359854')">Start Video Call</button>
</ion-slide>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
    goToPage(url : string) {
        window.open(url, '_self');
  }
}
```

Please help me to fix. Thank you

Comment: inappbrowser may help u...check it once

Answer (score 0):

@anggaerlangga you can use InAppBrowser to open an external link. because IONIC is not a web application you have to use any browser for open external URL. I will show you how can you use the InAppBrowser.

1. first of all you have to install InAppBrowser NPM from the ionic native.
2. `import { InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';`
3. `let baseurl = 'your url';
     let target = "_blank";
     this.iab.create(baseurl,target);`

Thank you. this will definitely help you.

Comment: before, I already use InAppBrowser to open my page. But, the problem is, cannot show / access front camera, Because, my page is WebRTC / video confrence page. If you have reference to support open webRTC page. Please inform me. Thanks